# Typescript complains about missing property that isn't missing

Tags: typescript

I have a simple interface defined as:

```
export interface ISnapShot {
  val: () => any;
  key: string;
  forEach: (child: ISnapShot) => boolean;
}
```

And yet when I attempt to implement the `forEach` method here:

```
export function snapshotToOrderedArray<T = IDictionary>(
  snap: ISnapShot,
  idProp = 'id'
): T[] {
  const output: T[] = [];
  snap.forEach((child: ISnapShot) => {
    const obj: any = child.val();
    const key: string = child.key;
    if (typeof obj !== 'object' ) {
      throw new Error(`Can't create a list from scalar values: "${obj}" | "${key}"`);
    }

    output.push( { ...{[idProp]: key }, ...obj } );

    return true;
  });

  return output as T[];
}
```

I get this error:

> [ts]
>   Argument of type '(child: ISnapShot) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISnapShot'.
>     Property 'val' is missing in type '(child: ISnapShot) => boolean'.

[image]

Not sure what to make of this error. The `ISnapShot` interface clearly does state that there is a `val` property. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: using version `2.4.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interface `ISnapShot`, the method `forEach` take one parameter of type ISnapShot and returns a `boolean`. The expected call is `snap.forEach(childSnap)`.

If you want an Array-like `forEach`, the argument must be a function, for instance *(using with [ES6 method shorthands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) for a better readibility)*:

```js
interface ISnapShot {
  // [...]
  forEach(mapper: (child: ISnapShot) => boolean): void;
}
```